# Query ContentProvider by content of BLOB column

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I need to query a ContentProvider based on the value of a binary blob column:

```
mContext.getContentResolver().query(
               contentUri,                          // Uri
               null,                                // Projection
               TableColumns.blobColumn + " = ?",    // Selection
               new String[] { blob_query },         // Selection Arguments
               null);                               // Order
```

Based on my reading of [SQLite literal values](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) it seems a blob with value `[0x01]` may be queried with the string literal  `X'01'`.

However I'm unable to query a record where `blobColumn` has value `new byte[] { (byte) 0x01 }`

#### Test code

```
 // Insert record
 byte[] blobData = new byte[] { (byte) 0x01 };

 ContentValues entry = new ContentValues();
 entry.put(TableColumns.blobColumn, blobData);
 Uri entryUri = getContext().getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, entry);

 // Query record by blob (fails)
 result = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            null,
            TableColumns.blobColumn + " = ?",
            new String[] {
              "x'01'"
            // None of the above or below work
            // "0x01"
            //"X'01'"
            //"01"
            },
            null);
 result.getCount() // 0

 // Query record by id (succeeds)
 result = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            null,
            TableColumns.idColumn + " = ?",
            new String[] {
              entryUri.getLastPathSegment()
            },
            null);
 result.getCount() // 1
```

Comment: Note that blob columns are not indexed so doing this kind of query requires iterating over every row in the database...not something you normally want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works:

```
    Cursor result = getContext().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            null,
            "quote(" + TableColumns.blobColumn + ") = ?",
            new String[] { "X'01'" },
            null);
```

I'll happily accept a better answer  if it exists.